# Python Pandas: Convert timedelta Value From Subtracting Two Dates Into Integer Datatype (AttributeError)

Tags: python, pandas, integer, division, timedelta

I have the following data set output (shown below) that was produced by the following code:

```
df_EVENT5_5['dtin'] = pd.to_datetime(df_EVENT5_5['dtin'])
df_EVENT5_5['age'] = df_EVENT5_5['dtin'].apply(dt.datetime.date) - df_EVENT5_5['dtbuilt'].apply(dt.datetime.date)

id  age
1   6252 days, 0:00:00
2   1800 days, 0:00:00
3   5873 days, 0:00:00
```

In the above data set, after running dtypes on the data frame, age appears to be an object.

I want to convert the "age" column into an integer datatype that only has the value of days.  Below is my desired output:

```
id  age
1   6252 
2   1800 
3   5873
```

I tried the following code:

```
df_EVENT5_5['age_no_days'] = df_EVENT5_5['age'].dt.total_seconds()/ (24 * 60 * 60)
```

Below is the error:

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: df_EVENT5_5['dtin'] = df_EVENT5_5['dtin'].dt.days   will also do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting an object column suggests to me that there are some values that can't be interpreted as proper timedeltas. If that's the case, I would use `pd.to_timedelta` with the argument `errors='coerce'`, then call `dt.days`:

```
df['age'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['age'],errors='coerce').dt.days
>>> df
   id   age
0   1  6252
1   2  1800
2   3  5873
```

Comment: I get the following error --> Overflow Error: int too big to convert